# Collapsing a padded div vs a padded fieldset

Tags: html, css

I've a drop down menu with the following structure:

- search-menu

  - item-heading
  - item-content (this is a fieldset element)

I've added some padding to the content element, but this causes problems when setting its max-height to 0 (ie the content element is closed and not visible), as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551234/how-to-remove-space-below-fieldset-legend)

The solution in the previous link (shown in the code below), only seems to work with divs, not fieldset elements. I'm sure I could just use another wrapper to solve this, but I'm interested in what I've missed as I can't see any differences in the inspector. No doubt I've missed something obvious here.

```css
    .div-1, .div-3 {
        padding: 40px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .div-2, .div-4 {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 0px;
        width: 100px;
        background: red;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="div-1">
        <fieldset class="div-2">
            Hello!
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    
    <div class="div-3">
        <div class="div-4">
            Hello!
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers give default styles to fieldset elements depending on the browser.  In Chrome it gets margin, padding and a border.  If you just set padding/margin to 0 and border to none it will behave as you'd expect with a height of 0.

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot - I was checking in firefox because I was using grid and it wasn't displaying those default styles in the inspector. Thanks.